# Locally monitoring services up/down on other Windows machines

Tags: windows, networking, services, surveillance

I have multiple services running on several Windows Server machine on our local network, and I would like to monitor them from my local Windows 7 machine, so I am notified when one or more services are down.  Please note that the tool needs to ask Windows about the state of the services, not look at whether e.g. a http port is responsive or not.

I have administrative rights on both machines, but not on the domain. I have the exact names of the services. My machine is not always on.  I can write small programs in .NET and big programs in Java.

I'd like something like a permanent version of the Outlook notification pane in the lower right corner.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default) have a tool called [PsTools suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx), which one of it's components is the PsList:

> PsList is part of a growing kit of Sysinternals command-line tools
>   that aid in the adminstration of local and remote systems named
>   PsTools.

Also, "sc.exe" tool can query status of remote computers from your network:

["Using Sc.exe and Netsvc.exe to Control Services Remotely"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166819/en-us)

[Example:](http://www.randomsupport.com/rs/blogs/index.php?title=howto_remotely_query_windows_service_inf&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1)

```
Get a list of Services that are running:
Y:\>sc \\"REMOTE_MACHINE_NAME" query type= service | find "SERVICE_NAME"
SERVICE_NAME: AudioSrv
SERVICE_NAME: Automatic LiveUpdate Scheduler
SERVICE_NAME: BESClient
SERVICE_NAME: CactusXMBService
SERVICE_NAME: ccEvtMgr
SERVICE_NAME: ccProxy
SERVICE_NAME: ccSetMgr
```

Comment: sc works here.  I'll have a closer look.